# First-child of Grandparent of an element JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've this html code :

```
<table id="MaTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>slip</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a class=".pop_admin"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and this Javascript code :

```
$("#MaTable tbody").on("click", ".pop_admin", function(event){
    alert(($(this).parents()[1]).find("td:first-child").tagName);
});
```

I'm trying to get the first "td" of my "tr" when clicking on my "a" with jquery selectors.
I can't put any ID on my button, or on my "tr", etc.. Because of my table is completed with a while.
If I run this code, the alert isn't popping.
I can find the tr with $(this).parents()[1], but when i'm trying to get the first child of it, I've got a lot of issues.
I'm getting bored because I tried a lot (children(), first(), ...). 
Please help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#MaTable tbody").on("click", ".pop_admin", function(event){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class name from `.pop_admin` to `pop_admin`, no need for that `.`

```
$("#MaTable tbody").on("click", ".pop_admin", function(event){
    alert($(this).parents("tr").find("td:first-child").text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/7WkZ5/